# 100% CPU consumption with Adobe Flash videos in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

100% cpu usage when streaming flash video with Chrome, but firefox use less than 50% of my cpu usage.

what causing this? 
also any workaround to fix it? 
thank you.

Comment: +1, chrome frequently hogs memory on my machine

Comment: Get use to it... and the problem lies with flash, not Chrome.

Comment: confirmed that dupe answer helps a LOT

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the Chrome's plugin "sandboxing". In Chrome forums they recommend to clear cache, but that works in some cases...

You can try Chromium and install Adobe Flash separately (Chrome includes a customized version of Flash).

Answer (score 1):

I think that Chrome is not the problem, the unique problem is Flash. Now I'm watching a video in window mode and CPU is nearly at 90%, but if I put it to fullscreen mode it decrease to 50%. Seems to be a problem with scaling video or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, it has to do with the standalone version of Flash and Chrome's integrated Flash conflicting with one another, trying to load both at the same time

Do the following:

- In Chrome's address bar, type "**about:plugins**" (no space between colon and plugins)
- This will bring up a list of plugins
- Look for the Flash plugin and when you find it, it may say 2 or more files. For example mine said 3 as shown here: Flash (3 files) - Version: 11,4,402,265
- Over to the far right is a DETAILS link. Click on it. This will bring up details for each file/version you have installed
- Look at the "**Location:**" of each version – some may be the integrated Chrome version (…Application Data\Google\Chrome etc) and the other is the standalone Adobe (formerly Macromedia) version which is in the …Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash etc directory.
- You don't want the integrated Chrome version(s). Click on "**Disable**" just under the Location(s) of the Chrome version to disable it (and it will become grayed out)
- Ensure that the standalone Adobe version is still enabled – if it is disabled (grayed out) click the ‘Enable’ link just under its Location to enable it) then close the Plugins tab

You're good to go. This should get rid of Flash constantly using 100% CPU for Flash videos.

Comment: i tried both.  didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Try using Lightspark, an alternative to Adobe's flash:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sparkers/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark
```

Source: http://www.unixmen.com/lightspark-a-good-alternative-to-adobe-flash-player-ppa-ubuntu-fedora-rpm/

Comment: i get the exact same spikes w lightspark + no swf